# Python, can't get assert_raises to work properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, nosetests

I am currently doing the "Learn Python the Hard Way" of Zed A. Shaw and I am having quite a bit of trouble with exercice 49 using assert_raises. Here is the code that I am using in my test file:

```
def test_parseVerb():
    assert_raises("ParserError",parser.parse_verb,[('stop', 'the'),
                                                   ('noun', 'bear')])
```

And this is the error that PowerShell is giving me:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: tests.parser_tests.test_parseVerb
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MrnMicro\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\sthma2\Documents\LPTHW\Projects\ex48\tests\parser_tests.py", line 37, in test_parseVer
b
    assert_raises("ParserError",parser.parse_verb,fail_list)
  File "C:\MrnMicro\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 476, in assertRaises
    callableObj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\MrnMicro\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 117, in __exit__
    if not issubclass(exc_type, self.expected):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 10 tests in 0.016s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I have no idea what is going on to be honest, if someone could help it would be much appreciated !

Thanks !

*EDIT*

```
def parse_verb(word_list):
    skip(word_list, 'stop')

    if peek(word_list) == 'verb':
        return match(word_list, 'verb')
    else:
        raise ParserError("Expected a verb next.")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide the actual class of the exception as first parameter, not a string containing the name, e.g.

```
assert_raises(ZeroDivisionError, operator.div,  1, 0)
```

The documentation is actually in the standard module [unittest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises), nose adapts the names to pep8.

Comment: Thanks! I used Exception as first parameter and it worked... Took me some time since I was raising the exception in a Else so it wasn't a "real" one like your example, however by looking at my ParserError class and realizing it was passing an Exception, I tried it and it worked.

Comment: I'd be more specific than `Exception`, as that covers all sorts of things you might not want, e.g. `KeyErrors`.

Comment: I've added a bit of code in my *EDIT*, how can I know what kind of error it would return to me with this kind of raise?

Comment: well, since you are raising a `ParseError`, that is what you should expect. Anything else is probably a bug and worth looking into.